# Unable to upload the file from local machine to server using php function

Tags: php

i am uploading the file in the servier i am using the below code

```
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile".$k]["tmp_name"],
  "photoalbum/".$_SESSION["almgid"]."/".$_FILES["uploadfile".$k]["name"]);
  $uploadfile =  "photoalbum/".$_SESSION["almgid"]."/".$_FILES["uploadfile".$k]["name"];
```

This code is working fine in the local but the images are not uploading in the server how to solve this issue please help me,

this is the error message i am receive during uploading the file in server

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(photoalbum/1cutebaby05.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/whspider/public_html/alumnimgmts/editprofile.php
```

i am already added the enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form, i already check the image size,

Comment: what are the read/write permissions of the upload directory and script?

Comment: Your code snippet seems to say `photoalbum/`, but the error says `studphoto/`. Which one is it?

Comment: Sorry it is photoalbum/ only i typed wrongly

Comment: make a habit of improving your question, once you notice flaws... :D

Comment: the file is uploaded in the localhost or it is neccessary to add assign permission to the server seperatly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a Linux box:

```
sudo chmod +w /path/to/photoalbum
```

Answer (score 0):

IF they are working in local server, then it is the problem related to to authorities.

try

```
chmod("photoalbum/".$_SESSION["almgid"]."/",0755); // OR 0777 during testing only
```

before `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: i am already  give the permission 0777 during the folder creation

Comment: Can you post what does $k hold.... is it correctly receiving the file you are asking?... check the `$_FILES` array using `print_r`

Comment: What about the `$_FILES`, post the output of `print_r($_FILES)`